# ansible-container variables in playbook

Tags: variables, docker, ansible, ansible-container

Using ansible-container (version 0.2.0) and trying to pass variables to the playbook (main.yml) using the `var_files` directive. No luck. Keep getting:

`ansible-container_1  | ERROR! 'var_files' is not a valid attribute for a Play`

The main.yml file has this block:

```
- hosts: all
  var_files:
      - postgres_vars.yml
```

Docs seem to suggest this is the right approach.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-container/container_yml/template.html#passing-variables-to-your-playbook

All suggestions appreciated.

Follow-up: 
Tried the suggestions listed in the docs and they don't seem to work either.

`sudo ansible-container --var-file ./ansible/postgres_vars.yml build --from-scratch`

fails with missing variable name error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `vars_files` (plural vars) in the playbook: [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-file-separation).

There's a typo in ansible-container example.

Comment: [submitted a pull request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-container/pull/344).